# How to get then button data-title value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to get the value of the button data-title (prbModalExt2.html) in jquery and insert it into a variable URL.

At this time the variable URL is created with the value `prbModalExt1.html`.

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="jumbotron"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-title="prbModalExt2.html">Show Modal</a></div>
    <div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = 'prbModalExt1.html';
        jQuery('#modellink').click(function (e) {
            $('.modal-container').load(url, function (result) {
                $('#myModal').modal({ show: true });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.data()` function from jQuery

```
$('#modallink').data('title');
```

More information about `.data()` can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get value like this

```
 var value = $('#modallink').data('title')
```

Then you can add in url as per your requirement through concatenation. Like

```
var url = 'prbModalExt1.html/'+value; or 
var url = 'prbModalExt1.html/?'+"title="+value;
```

Comment: welcome @JoseRodriguez. can you accept this as answer?? if this solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to you to get data-title

```js
$(function(){
 $('#modallink').click(function(){
     // .....   
      alert($('#modallink').data('title'))
 })
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="modallink" data-title="Click Me" value="Click Here"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch your anchor tag with class and on click event you can use data to catch your value.

```js
$("a.btn-primary").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).data('title'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container ">
  <div class="jumbotron"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-title="prbModalExt2.html">Show Modal</a></div>
  <div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>
```